# Help in calculating of gradient

Tags: derivatives

I have a function f(D) = $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2}(o_n-Dy_n)^T*\phi^{-1}*(o_n-Dy_n)$

I want to know what will be its gradient with respect to D. I tried a couple of things but I am not sure what its gradient should be. Can anyone give me some good resources where I find it easier to calculate gradient of functions

The above function is similar to multivariate gaussian distribution where mean is a linear function of $y_n$

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Are these supposed to be matrices? vectors? etc? Can you explain what $o_n$ is? Is $*$ supposed to be conjugation, or multiplication?

Comment: * is multiplication operator $o_n$ and $y_n$ are vectors and D is a matrix

Comment: If it's not too much trouble to you, what is $\phi$? In the question, please define everything that you use.

Comment: basically it is similar to multivariate gaussian distribution

Comment: Found the solution here orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf. Never mind.Close this topic

Answer (score 1):

A good resource with a large number of formulas for differentiating functions  in terms of vectors and matrices is [The Matrix Cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). This is where the OP found an answer to the question. Alternatively, one can approach the derivative in directional sense, plugging in $D+\epsilon H$ and extracting the coefficient of $\epsilon$ from
$$f(D+\epsilon H)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2}(o_n-Dy_n-\epsilon Hy_n)^T*\phi^{-1}*(o_n-Dy_n-\epsilon Hy_n) \tag1$$
The result is 
$$-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2}(Hy_n)^T*\phi^{-1}*(o_n-Dy_n)-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2}(o_n-Dy_n )^T*\phi^{-1}*( Hy_n) \tag2$$
The formula (2) defines a linear function of $H$; this linear function is the derivative of $f$ at $D$.